# Реализация операций с дробями

Tags: c++, ооп, числа

Суть задания:

Реализовать класс Fraction для работы с дробными числами, число представлено двумя 
 полями: целая часть (long int) и дробная часть (unsigned short int). Реализовать 
 сложение, вычитание, умножение и сравнение.

Пример моей реализации:

```
class Fraction{
private:
    long int integer;
    unsigned short int fractional;
public:
void Read(){
        cin >> integer;
        cin >> fractional;
    }
    bool isEq(const Fraction& obj){
        if(integer == obj.integer && fractional == obj.fractional){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    void Sum(const Fraction& obj){
        integer += obj.integer;
        fractional += obj.fractional;
    }
    void Display(){
        cout << integer << "." << fractional << endl;
    }
};
```

Вопрос:
При сложении дробей может возникнуть ситуация, когда сумма дробной части превышает 1 (3.25 + 3.85 = 7.1 (В программе выходит 6.110)). Как реализовать корректное сложение дробной части?

Вопрос 2: Возможно ли представить дробную часть которая начинается с "0" (.001) используя unsigned short int?

Comment: разве они не будут всегда больше 1 если хранятся в типе int

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Что именно у вас хранится в `fractional`??? Как там представляется дробная часть? Например, как там будет представлено `0.00003` и чем оно будет отличаться от представления `0.03`?

Comment: Какой странный тип. Обычно всё-таки хранят числитель и знаменатель. Вы точно правильно задание поняли?

Comment: в fractional хранится дробная часть числа, думаю не будет никакого отличия между 0.0375 0.000375. Меня это тоже сбило с толку

Comment: задание передано дословно

Comment: при дроби .375 и .210 условие сработает неверно

Comment: Если в вашем представлении нет возможности отличить `0.0375` от `0.000375`, то дальше и говорить не о чем. Подход неработоспособен в принципе. Вердикт окончателен, тема закрыта. Начинайте с начала: с разработки жизнеспособного представления. То, что вы придумали пока, в принципе пригодно для представлений *с фиксированной точкой*. Но для этого вам нужно выбрать, где вы будете фиксировать точку.

Comment: Может быть дробная часть должна определяться как `fractional / 2^16`. Не вижу других вариантов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш класс  должен выглядеть совершенно иначе, но все же ответ на первый вопрос. Нужно определять количество цифр у максимального числа, и после этого все легко:

```
void Sum(const Fraction& obj) {
    integer += obj.integer;
    unsigned short e = 10,
        max = std::max(fractional, obj.fractional);
    fractional += obj.fractional;
    while (max > e)
        e *= 10;
    if (fractional > e) {
        fractional %= e;
        ++integer;
    }           
}
```

Ответ на второй вопрос: возможно, но нужно  хранить в классе количество  этих  нулей

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, предполагается, что в дробной части хранятся сотые.

```
void Sum(const Fraction& obj) {
    integer += obj.integer;
    fractional += obj.fractional;
    integer += fractional / 100;
    fractional = fractional % 100;
}

cout << integer << "." << /* add 0 if needed */fractional << endl;
```

Comment: @ARHovsepyan для двухзначных дробных частей